# Phase after a pilot program

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase that communicates a program's phase after it's pilot phase (sorry for the redundancy)

So if HUD has a pilot program right now, but I want to formulate a question of when will this program be (blank this is word I am looking for)

Thank you

Comment: I think the word "syndicated" applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasal verb *go live* is often used, as in (eg) “When will this program go live?”  Also see wiktionary's entry for *[go-live](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go-live)* as a noun.  As a phrasal verb, *go live* doesn't specifically denote technology based programs, so can be used with any program that has a pilot phase followed by an operational phase.

Also consider terms like *become active, scale up, be open, in production,* and *operational*.  Eg: “HUD's teardown program went operational on 3 July” and “When will this program be operational?”

Comment: I am afraid to use go-live for a non-technology based program. This is not a website nor an app, but rather a government sponsored program having to do with mortgages and home loans. I think of go-live as something related to internet. Do think go-live may imply related to technology based programs?

Comment: @IberoMedia – I added a note

Answer (score 1):

After a program's successful pilot comes its *[roll out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/roll-out_1)*.

So you can ask, "When will this program be rolled out?"